# Simple Java regular expression matching fails

Tags: java, regex

Before y'all jump on me for posting something similar to previous questions asked, yes, there seem to be a number of regex related questions but nothing which seems to help me, or at least that I can see.

I am trying to parse strings in JAVA using `PATTERN` and `MATCHER` and am really having no joy. My regular expression seems to match my input string when I use a few of the online regular expression testing websites but Java simply does not match my expression.

My input string is:

`"Big apple" title="Little Apple" type="Container" url="http://malcolm.com/testing"`

The regular expression I am using to match is `".*" title="(.*)" type="Container" url="(.*)"`

Essentially I want to pull out the text within the second and the fourth set of quotes. There will always be 4 sets of quotes with text within and around.

I am coding as follows:

Variable `XMLSubstring` contains the string above (including the quotes) and is as stated, even when I print it out.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".* title=\"(.*)\" type=\"Container\" url=\"(.*)\"");

m = p.matcher(XMLSubstring);
```

It doesn't appear to be rocket science I'm attempting but I'm pulling my hair out trying to debug the bloody thing.

Is there something wrong with my regex pattern?
Is there something wrong with the code I am using?
Am I simply a moron and should stop coding with immediate effect?

EDIT & UPDATE: I have found the problem. My string had a space at the end of it which was breaking the parser! How silly, and I think based on that, I need to accept the third suggestion of mine and give up programming. Thanks all for your assistance.

Comment: Also, you need to use two backslashes \\ to escape characters within a Java regex.  You should really start by reading [the documentation for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)...

Comment: Thanks jahroy for your feedback. In truth my posting has .* in all three spots but somehow when my question is posted the first two * do not show.

Comment: My pattern is ".*" title="(.*)" type="Container" url="(.*)"

Comment: Ok.  My apologies for that... It's just the syntax engine at StackOverflow I guess.  But really, there are lots of tutorials out there.

Comment: Fair enough comment, but I have used regex's quite a bit in PERL many years back so do have a basic understanding of them. What is throwing me is that the various online regex testers seem ot agree that my regex is OK against the input text!

Comment: It's important to know that regex syntax varies in different contexts.  The biggest difference about Java vs other places (perl, JavaScript) is that you often have to use a second backslash to escape backslashes.  This is because you're first escaping a special character within the string, then need to escape it again for the regex compiler.  My apologies for clearly being too harsh in my initial comments.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
    String str="\"Big apple\" title=\"Little Apple\" type=\"Container\" url=\"http://malcolm.com/testing\"";

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".* title=\\\".*\\\" type=\\\"Container\\\" url=\\\".*\\\"");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
```

Comment: So you're saying the problem is that he didn't escape the quote characters for the regex parser?  Not true; `"` has no special meaning in a regex, so you only need the one backslash to get it past the *Java* compiler.  Adding the backslash didn't break anything, but it didn't fix the problem.  Your regex works because (as it turns out) the original regex was okay; it was the input that was broken.